# "Отложить в долгий ящик"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло это выражение? Что такое этот "долгий ящик"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть предположение, будто это словосочетание, означающее «дать делу длительную отсрочку», «надолго задержать его решение», возникло еще в Московской Руси, триста лет назад.

Царь Алексей, отец Петра I, приказал в селе Коломенском перед своим дворцом установить длинный ящик, куда всякий мог бы опустить свою жалобу. Жалобы опускались, но дождаться решений было очень не легко; часто до того проходили месяцы и годы. Народ переименовал этот «длинный» ящик в «долгий».

Трудно, однако, поручится за точность этого объяснения: ведь говорим мы не «опустить» или не «положить», а «отложить в долгий ящик». Можно думать, что выражение если и не родилось, то закрепилось в речи позднее, в «присутствиях» - учреждениях  XIX века. Тогдашние чиновники, принимая разные прошения, жалобы и ходатайства, несомненно, сортировали их, раскладывая по разным ящикам. «Долгим» мог называться  тот, куда откладывались самые неспешные дела. Понятно, что такого ящика просители боялись.

Кстати сказать, нет надобности считать, что кто-то когда-то специально переименовал «длинный» ящик в «долгий»: во многих местах нашей страны в народном языке «долгий» именно и значит «длинный».

Тот же смысл имеет и родившееся позднее выражение «положить под сукно». Сукном покрывали столы в российских канцеляриях.

Comment: @olsa, история с переименованием "длинного" в "долгий" явно за уши притянута. По наиболее популярной версии, ящик изначально был окрещен "долгим", длинным он вряд ли был, а если и был, то это не було бы его характеристическим свойством. Скорее как раз длинный - это позднейшая интерепретация. А вообще "длинный" и "долгий" - родственны, неудивительно, что где-то эти значения смешиваются.

Вот насчет отложить-положить тут конечно, серьёзнее, но не уверен, что это не позднейшее переосмысление тех же чиновников на картотеке.

Answer (score 1):

К сказаному могу добавить еще одну версию . Возможно, выражение - прямая калька с немецкого "etwas in die lange Truhe legen".

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "положить в долгий ящик" - калька с немецкого (etwas in die lange Truhe legen ("положить что-либо в долгий сундук")). Долгим ящиком иронически называли гроб. Он продолговатый, долгий в том же смысле, что и в поговорке "волос долог, да ум короток", долгополый, долговязый, долгорукий... "Положить дело в долгий ящик" - значит похоронить это дело. Никаких "долгих ящиков" для писем или жалоб при Алексее Михайловиче наверняка не было, ибо грамотность была в те годы большой редкостью (даже в начале 20-го века в России было 80% неграмотных), бумага была дорога. Не было такого бумажного потока, для которого потребовался бы специальный ящик. В исторических документах об этих ящиках упоминаний нет. Похоже на фантазию. В позднейшее время ирония этого выражения была утрачена, и вместо "положить в долгий ящик" стали говорить "отложить в долгий ящик". Изменили смысл. Ну и придумали объяснение. Кстати, столы с выдвижными ящиками появились в России (массово) намного позднее царствования Алексея Михайловича. Даже у Гоголя Акакий Акакиевич клал бумаги "под сукно". В одной русской повести 18 века я встретил фразу, что "по смерти дядюшки к наследнику явились во множестве изготовители долгих ящиков с предложением своих услуг". Ясно, что это о гробовщиках "

Добавлю, что во времена Алексея Михайловича не было ещё в России и почты. Так что, и почтовых ящиков не было (не только "долгих" в том смысле как некоторые считают теперь). Письма передавались с гонцами или с нарочными, часто с просьбой "передать лично в руки".  См. стихотворение Ал.Конст. Толстого "Василий Шибанов" (там времена Ивана Грозного, много позднее Алексея Тишайшего).

Comment: Дурацкое объяснение про специальный ящик было встечено в книге выпущенной в советское время. Но фраза была "положить в долгий ящик". А секретеры вообще распространились поздно, они-то появились только перед французкой революцией, а вариант с тумбой, более известный нам - гораздо позже.

Comment: *там времена Ивана Грозного, много позднее Алексея Тишайшего* — это в каком смысле "позднее"?